# vector subscrip out of range error c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, vector

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>  
#include <iomanip>  
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std;  


void determine_grade (double &, char & );  
double calc_average (vector <double> averagevector);  
double find_highest (vector <double> highestvector);  
double find_lowest (vector <double> lowestvector);  




int main ()  
{  
double average = 0.00;  
double highest = 0.00;  
double lowest = 0.00;  
double input;   
char letter;
double score = 0;
vector <double> vecinput(0);  

for (int i = 0; i < vecinput.size(); i++)  
 {  
  cout << " Enter result " << vecinput[i] << "(or -1 if no more result):";
  cin >> input;  
  vecinput[i] = input; 
  if (input < 0 || input > 100) 
  {
      cout << " Invalid Input";
  }
  else(input == -1);
  {
      break;
  }


}

determine_grade(score, letter);

cout << " Summary of the Results:" << endl;  
cout << " Result" << vecinput.size()<<   
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << score << "Grade" << letter << "\n";

average = calc_average(vecinput);  
cout << " The average of the results =" << setprecision (2) << fixed  << average <<       "\n";  


lowest = find_lowest(vecinput);  
cout << " The lowest of the results =" << setprecision (2)<< fixed << lowest << "\n";  


highest = find_highest(vecinput);  
cout << " The highest of the results =" << setprecision (2) << fixed << highest << "\n";  


system ("Pause");  
return 0;  
}



double calc_average(vector <double> averagevector) // This function will find the  average off the results.  
{  
double total = 0.00;  
double average = 0.00;  
for (int i = 0; i < averagevector.size(); ++i)  
{  
    total += averagevector[i];  
}  
average = (double) total / averagevector.size();   
return average;  
  }  


  double find_highest (vector <double> highestvector) // This function will find the  higest grade of the results.  
{  
double max= 0.00;  
max = *max_element(highestvector.begin(),highestvector.end());

 return max;
}  
double find_lowest (vector <double> lowestvector) // This function will find the lowest     grade of the results.  
{  
 double min = 0.00;
min = *min_element(lowestvector.begin(),lowestvector.end());

 return min;
}  


void determine_grade (double &num, char &grade)  
{  

if (num >= 90 && num <= 100)  
    grade = 'A';  
    else if (num >= 70 && num <= 89)  
    grade = 'B';  
    else if (num >= 60 && num <= 69 )  
    grade = 'C';  
    else if (num >= 50 && num <= 59)  
    grade = 'P';  
    else   
    grade = 'U';  



    }
```

I am trying to write a program which has to display the highest, the lowest grade. I have to also display the average, and also the letter grade. I am getting a vector subscript out of range error. on line 932  whenever I try to run this program. I am not sure what I have done wrong.

Now I am getting an error that vector iterator not differenciable

Comment: I don't want to spoil the fun, but if you can use the new C++ 2011 standard there's single function which will can replace both `find_highest` and `find_lowest`. Also, for calculating the average, you could make use of the ready-made function for creating the sum of values in a range.

Comment: `std::vector<double> vecinput(0);` is delcaring a vector of size `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i <= vecinput.size()
```

`.size()` returns the size of the vector, and their indices are zero-based, so you are going one past the end of the vector.

Use `<` instead of `<=`.

Also learn how to use a debugger, because you can figure out exactly where the error is occurring with one.

Comment: Seconded. The error is telling you exactly what is wrong and on which source code file line number.You are using visual studio, it should even stop and highlight the line for you.

Comment: Hi now I am getting an error that vector iterator not dereferencable after doing the change

Comment: @user2985086 your `max_element` functions are probably dereferencing the second iterator you pass them, which is also one past the end.

Comment: @user2985086 `vector.end()` gives an iterator to one past the end of the vector, you cannot dereference it. `vector.end() - 1` is a pointer to the last element (as long as it has at least one element)

Comment: I am still kind of confused because I am new to programming